# Route Model Binding not working Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, model

Route Model Binding not working 
model: Accommodation
Controller: AccommodationController
Route::resource('accommodation', 'AccommodationController');
Working

```
public function index()
    {
        $accommodation = Accommodation::get();
        return view('admin.accommodations.index', compact('accommodation'));
    }
```

Not working

```
public function index(Accommodation $accommodation)
    {
        return view('admin.accommodations.index', compact('accommodation'));
    }
```

Comment: Resource routes has very defined methods. It is 7 methods and some of those accept parameters and some of those don't expect parameters. In default resource routes index doesn't expect paramter. But show method/route expect it. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

You can see your route list in your php artisan terminal to avoid confusion.Use command.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Then see in name list what was name , then put in your route function.

However, I think your route will be

```
admin.accommodation
```

remove 's'.

Comment: ```|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/accommodation                                      | accommodation.index          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AccommodationController@index                     | web                                                                                                                      |
route is ok